# Use PHP to Convert Email Text to a Link

Tags: php, mailto

Based on a question I had answered here ( [Use PHP to Replace HTML with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883967/use-php-to-replace-html-with-html) ), I'd like to be able to filter my output text for email addresses, and convert those text emails to "mailto" links.

Here's the PHP code that works, but only for converting some HTML to other HTML. What I've tried to do is have this function look for an email address, and convert it to a "mailto" link. For whatever reason, the code doesn't convert the email addresses. Here's my PHP:

```
function text_filter($string) {
    $search  = array('<p>__</p>',   '/[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/');
    $replace = array('<hr />',      '<a href="mailto:$2">$2</a>');
    $processed_string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
    echo $processed_string;
}
```

When I use this function for output, this is what the code looks like:

```
<?php text_filter( get_the_content() ); ?>
```

Comment: We know what a function call looks like, show us the *output*. *edit*: actually, I can tell you it won't work because `str_replace()` does not recognize regular expressions. Use `preg_replace()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `str_replace()` doesn't use regular expressions, rewritten with `preg_replace()`.
2. Added delimiters to first matching expression.
3. Fixed replacement from `$1` to `$2`.

```
function text_filter($string) {
    $search  = array('/<p>__<\/p>/', '/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})/');
    $replace = array('<hr />', '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');
    $processed_string = preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
    echo $processed_string;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I now have another issue. There is a WordPress plugin I'm using that obfuscates email addresses. I had to disable this plugin so that the above function would work. Is there a way to also add some sort of email obfuscation along with this code? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Just discovered a 2nd issue:  If a mailto email address already exists within the page, the above function will also attempt to convert that email. Unfortunately, some of the HTML code is added before the email mailto link, e.g. "mail@example.com?subject=Subject">", where mail@example.com is a fully-functional / clickable mailto link. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

@Adam Baney - This will work even when used repeatedly.

```html
// EMAILS
$str =  preg_replace('~(^|[\s\.,;\n\(])([a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})~',
  '$1<a href="mailto:$2">$2</a>',
  $str);

// PHONE NUMBERS
$str =  preg_replace_callback('~(^|[\s\.,;\n\(])(?<! )([0-9 \+\(\)]{9,})~', function($m) {
  return $m[1].'<a href="tel:'.preg_replace('~[^0-9\+]~', '', $m[2]).'">'.$m[2].'</a>';
}, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `str_replace` to do a regular expression replace.

You will need to split the actions up.

```
function text_filter($string) {
    $search  = array('<p>__</p>');
    $replace = array('<hr />');
    $processed_string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
$processed_string = preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/','<a href="mailto:$2">$2</a>',$processed_string);
    echo $processed_string;
}
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php for preg replacing.

Comment: Thank you for your help! You were right about the preg_replace, however, the code you supplied didn't work. The email addresses disappeared completely. The 2 underscores surrounded by P tags were replaced with a horizontal rule. Sammitch's answer below worked perfectly!

Comment: Great to hear, didn't test the reqular expression whatsoever, so it's possible it wouldn't work ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function obfuscate_email($content){

    $pattern = '#([0-9a-z]([-_.]?[0-9a-z])*@[0-9a-z]([-.]?[0-9a-z])*\\.';
    $pattern .= '[a-wyz][a-z](fo|g|l|m|mes|o|op|pa|ro|seum|t|u|v|z)?)#i';
    $replacement = '<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>';
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    return $content;

}
```

And add filter

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'obfuscate_email' );
```

Comment: This works great with converting emails to "emailto" links, however, with an email address that is already linked, this doesn't work. Here's the HTML that's output: `<a href="mailto:<a href="mailto:email@test.com">email@test.com</a>"><a href="mailto:email@test.com">email@test.com</a></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it in order so that it would work with existing html links in text:

```
function html_parse_text($text)
{    
    $text = preg_replace("/(?<!\")(((f|ht){1}tps?:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/",
            '<a href="\\1" target=_blank>\\1</a>', $text);       
    $text = preg_replace("/([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/",
            '\\1<a href="http://\\2" target=_blank>\\2</a>', $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/(?<!\")([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})/",
            '<a href="mailto:\\1" target=_blank>\\1</a>', $text);

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Same comment as above... This works great with converting emails to "emailto" links, however, with an email address that is already linked, this doesn't work. Here's the HTML that's output: `<a href="mailto:<a href="mailto:email@test.com">email@test.com</a>"><a href="mailto:email@test.com">email@test.com</a></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of this that seems to work for me. I've added + char to handle "plus addressing" (like some+email@address.com)

```
function replaceemail($text) {-
    $ex = "/([a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})/";
    preg_match_all($ex, $text, $url);
    foreach($url[0] as $k=>$v) $text = str_replace($url[0][$k], '<a href="mailto:'.$url[0][$k].'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">'.$url[0][$k].'</a>', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: The output HTML gets really messy, repeating the HTML link in the site's text many times. Here's a screen shot: http://is.gd/bnAnQU